# Why is this map into the Lewy hypersurface a bijection?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

> Let $\mathbb{S}^{2N - 1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^N$ and let $L$
> be the Lewy hypersurface, which is defined by
> $$
> \operatorname{Im} Z_N = \sum_{j = 0}^{N - 1} |Z_j|^2.
> $$
> Let $H(\mathbf{Z}):\mathbb{S}^{2N - 1} \to L$ be
> a holomorphic rational mapping $ H(\mathbf{Z}) = (H_1(\mathbf{Z}), \dots, H_N(\mathbf{Z})) $ defined by $$ H_j(\mathbf{Z}) = \frac{iZ_j}{1 - Z_N}$$ for $j = 1, \dots, N - 1$, and
> $$ H_N(\mathbf{Z}) = \frac{i(Z_N + 1)}{1 - Z_N}. $$
> Prove that $H$ is a bijection.

The problem statement is as above. This is from a "reader should easily be able to check" comment in Baouend, Ebenfelt, and Rothschild's *Real Submanifolds in Complex Space and their Mappings.* Here is my attempt:

We show that $H$ is surjective.
Let $\mathbf{U} = (U_1,\dots,U_N) = (U_1,\dots,V_N + iW_N) \in L \subset \mathbb{C}^N$.
Then by the definition of the Lewy hypersurface,
we compute:
$$
V_N + iW_N  = V_N + i \sum_{j = 1}^{N - 1} |U_j|^2 = \frac{i(Z_N + 1)}{1 - Z_N}.
$$

I'm a bit stuck at this point. This doesn't seem terribly complicated, maybe just algebraic manipulation. But it doesn't seem like there's a nice way to get an expression for $\mathbf{Z}$ in terms of the components of $\mathbf{U}$ such that $\mathbf{U} \mapsto \mathbf{Z}$. We also know $\mathbf{Z}$ is on the sphere, but I don't immediately see how we can use that.

Comment: First of all, this is $\Bbb S^{2N-1}$. What is the Lewy hypersurface? I know from years ago, but you should write your question as clearly as possible. Before doing surjectivity, have you checked that $H$ maps to $L$?